# How to correctly send ~m over ssh using asyncSSH library in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, networking, ssh

I'm trying to send this sequence below over asyncSSH

```
Enter(Carriage return)  
~m
```

I have tried that with interactive ssh using the OpenSSH server on Ubuntu 18.04.
OpenSSH has Tilde as an escape character so I send this. Tilde two times. And it works as expected.

```
Enter(Carriage return)  
~~m
```

but I have tried to send the same sequence with multiple approaches but it doesn't make any effect on the ssh shell using asyncSSH library.

I have tried all these sequences below

```
self._conn.send("\n~m")
self._conn.send("\n~~m")
self._conn.send("\x0d~m")
self._conn.send("\x0d~~m")
```

For Reference, you can check where this sequence originates and is needed on open-gear devices.
https://opengear.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/216373543-Communicating-with-serial-port-connected-devices

```
When connected to a port, use the chooser escape sequence of <enter>~m
```

Brief Explanation about the scenario,
Opengear is a device that connects to the console of network devices. when I connect to the device console port for going back to the menu to select another port I need to enter this sequence.

Any help sincerely appreciated. Thanks